# How to validate Amazon SessionToken / Cognito?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, asp.net-web-api2, amazon-cognito

I am creating a proof of concept for using amazon cognito for the Developer Authenticated Identities Authflow. The main difference is I plan to use the Credentials provided by AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity in my API instead of the directly using

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/authentication-flow.html

From the implementation I've seen it usually uses S3 as an example resource it tries to access. In my case, I just want to know if the credential provided is valid.

---

mobile sends username / password -> developer server authenticates and generates openIdToken (GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity)

mobile sends openId token -> developer server get credentials (accessKeyId, secretAccessKey, sessionToken) with AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity

mobile sends accesskey accessSecret and sessionToken to server -> **How do I validate if the credentials are correct?**

Comment: How do you validate whether they are "correct" *for what?*

Comment: I intend to use it as an OAuth token provider. I want to use Amazon STS to manage generating the token and their validity similar to how facebook and google.